# componentDidCatch is being called multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a component on click of a button. This component throws an error and is being wrapped by Error-Boundary. So from my understanding from the docs, Error-Boundary should be called and the error should be thrown only once. But I noticed that the error is being thrown multiple times in the prod environment too.

My componentDidCatch looks like:

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
  this.hasError = true;
  this.error = error;
  this.severity = this.props.severity;
}
```

When I console.log inside componentDidCatch it prints it some 9 times.

My components are being wrapped in the following way:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
 <ErrorBoundary severity="FATAL">
  <App />
 </ErrorBoundary>
 </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App is my main component. App again is rendering other components.

```
<ErrorBoundary severity="FATAL">
   <component1 />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The error is being displayed 9 times. Can anyone please help me in understanding why the error is being thrown these many times?

Comment: Nobody but you can say why the error is thrown because nobody but you saw your code. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's off-topic and can be closed. The problem is what the error says. An object is undefined.

Comment: @estus how about you read the question he asks... it's not about what the error says :)

Comment: @amal Your component rerenders multiple times, thats why componentDidCatch gets called multiple times. I suggest you to move componentDidCatch to the top component, that way it will catch all errors that happen in the child components.

Comment: @Stundji My comment is not about what the error says. The point is that the question breaks SO rules and requires users to speculate on the code, while it could be just posted.

Comment: @Stundji I have a generic ErrorBoundary component which wraps the child components just as it is shown in the docs. I have also wrapped my sub-components inside ErrorBoundary so that if a single component fails, the entire application doesn't crash.

Comment: @estus Sorry if the error makes the question confusing. I simply wanted if anyone has faced the same problem or have any ideas as to what might be causing component to render multiple times as I am not using state in my componentDidCatch. Editing the question to remove the error message :)

Comment: As Stundji already suggested, there are multiple errors because inner error boundary `<ErrorBoundary severity="FATAL"><component1 />...` is remounted. Currently the question doesn't contain any hints why this may happen.